# How do you change line-spacing on a SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How do you change the leading (line-spacing) on a multi-line SKLabelNode?

Do users of SpriteKit simply have to accept whatever default Apple gives?

I see no way in the APIs to change it. Given it must wrap lower-level APIs, I would think there may be a way to do it. But Googling avails me naught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **iOS11+** You can use a `NSAttributedString` and a custom paragraphStyle

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 20
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 20
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 20
let labelNode = SKLabelNode(attributedText: .init(string: "Hello World\nYour custom string", attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]))
```